# Replacing several sub-version numbers with another one using PowerShell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I'm have several Puppet manifests with version information about the software that my company develops. It looks something like this:

```puppet
app_version     => '11.6.1',
```

I need to change the version number to a sub-version that just adds a letter at the end of the version number, so that it looks like this for example:

```puppet
app_version     => '11.6.1d',
```

My manifests contain already some subversions, so you would have already some 11.6.1a.
I'm using a hashtable to store the different versions and replacement values:

```bsh
$versions = @{
  '11.6.1[a-zA-Z]'  = '11.6.1b';
  '11.7.0[a-zA-Z]'  = '11.7.0d';
  '11.7.2[a-zA-Z]'  = '11.7.2b';
  '11.8.6[a-zA-Z]'  = '11.8.6c';
  '11.8.13[a-zA-Z]' = '11.8.13b'
}
```

I'm having issues with this because using the the version number followed with `[a-zA-z]` will only change the subversions that contain a letter after the version number.

What expression do I need to use in `$versions` so that it looks at versions that are 11.6.1 OR 11.6.1 + a letter after the 1?

Comment: As a side-note, I'd recommend storing that kind of information in Hiera rather than Puppet manifests. Makes it a lot easier to manage, both manually and programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a regular expression to match both `11.6.1` and `11.6.1d`, you probably want:

```
11.6.1[a-zA-Z]?
```

Which optionally matches the last set (`[a-zA-Z]`) if it exists, but does not if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Since PowerShell is case-insensitive by default `11.6.1[a-z]?` should suffice.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers not a powershell user, so you probably know better, just basing it off of the pattern OP provided originally.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for, the ? solved my problem.